# Correct way of using a windows dll in D?

Tags: windows, dll, d

I have a small dll that i want to use with the [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29) language. I'm assuming it has been written in C. These are the files i have access to and they exist in the same directory as my program.:

- b3d.dll
- blitz3dsdk.exp
- blitz3dsdk.lib
- blitz3dsdk.h

Here's what i've tried to get D to use this dll.

---

**test.d**

```
pragma(lib, "blitz3dsdk.lib");

int main(string[] Args)
{
    bbBeginBlitz3D();
    bbEndBlitz3D();

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile:** dmd test.d -w -wi -debug
**Result:** `Error 43: Not a Valid Library File.`

---

**Blitz3DSDK.d**

```
module Blitz3DSDK;

// __declspec(dllimport) int bbBeginBlitz3D() - from the header file.
export extern (Windows) int bbBeginBlitz3D();

// __declspec(dllimport) void bbEndBlitz3D() - from the header file.
export extern (Windows) void bbEndBlitz3D();
```

**test.d**

```
import Blitz3DSDK;

int main(string[] Args)
{
    bbBeginBlitz3D();
    bbEndBlitz3D();

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile:** dmd test.d -w -wi -debug
**Result:** `Error 42: Symbol Undefined _bbBeginBlitz3D@0` `Error 42: Symbol Undefined _bbEndBlitz3D@0`

---

Any ideas how to use this dll or any helpful up to date online guides would be appreciated. It's been a while since i've fiddled with native code and shared libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following CyberShadow's advice i used the `coffimplib` tool to convert the `blitz3dsdk.lib` file to be in OMF format and imported that using a pragma. I then defined the external functions it contains inside an `extern (C)` block.

Example:

```
pragma(lib, "new.lib");

extern (C)
{
    int bbBeginBlitz3D();
    void bbEndBlitz3D();
}

int main(string[] Args)
{
    bbBeginBlitz3D();
    bbEndBlitz3D();

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried it with a few more functions from this dll following the guideline from [this page](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/htomodule.html) for conversion of some types, etc and all works great.

Answer (score 5):

The library file is probably in the COFF format. Use `coffimplib` to convert it to an OMF library usable with D's linker, or `implib` to create an import library from the DLL.

`export` is used when exporting functions from a DLL, not for importing them.